# Unable to change memory allocation in Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to increase the the Memory Allocation for some of my Cloud Function for past few hours. If I change it and deploy the Memory Allocation keeps staying in 512 MiB. It was working when I tried it few days back.

This is what I am doing,

[Click on edit in function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d09dj.png)

[Change Memory allocated to 2 GiB and click Next & Deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2l4m.png)

[The memory allocated remain 512 MiB after deploying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckFGJ.png)

What am I doing wrong ? Can someone help me out on this please?

Comment: Can you edit your question and actually add what have you tried so it can be figured out what's wrong?

Comment: Hi, added some screenshots to add more context.

Comment: Does the deploy is successful? I mean, there are no issues with code? Normally when a function is not deployed correctly it rolls back to the old configuration. Also do not post external links to images, add them in the post

Answer (score 1):

I'm **unable** to repro your experience using Cloud Console and `gcloud`.

```sh
gcloud functions describe ${NAME} \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(availableMemoryMb)"
256
```

Then revise it in the Console to `256MB` and:

```sh
gcloud functions describe ${NAME} \
--region=${ERGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(availableMemoryMb)"
512
```

Then revise it to `1024MB` using `gcloud deploy`:

```sh
gcloud functions deploy ${NAME} \
--trigger-http \
--entry-point=${FUNCTION} \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--memory=1024MB

gcloud functions describe ${NAME} \
--region=${ERGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(availableMemoryMb)"
1024
```